# How to create a custom directive for a JSON response received

Tags: angularjs, json

I wanted to create a custom directive addressing the scope to one of the object

JavaScript:

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);

module.controller('FoodCourtMenuController', function ($scope) {
$scope.GetMenu = function () {
    var json = '[{"FoodCourtName":"Fiesta","FoodCourtDetails":[{"VendorName":"Adigas","VendorDetails":[{"FoodTypeName":"Breakfast","FoodTypeDetails":[{"Name":"Aloo paratha","Price":"Rs. 60","IsVeg":"True","ItemDetails":"2 nos"},{"Name":"North indian meal","Price":"Rs. 60","IsVeg":"True","ItemDetails":"sweet + roti"}]},{"FoodTypeName":"Lunch","FoodTypeDetails":[{"Name":"Dosa","Price":"Rs. 60","IsVeg":"True","ItemDetails":""},{"Name":"South indian meal","Price":"Rs. 80","IsVeg":"True","ItemDetails":"sweet + rice"}]}]},{"VendorName":"Kaamath","VendorDetails":[{"FoodTypeName":"Breakfast","FoodTypeDetails":[{"Name":"Sprouts","Price":"Rs. 60","IsVeg":"True","ItemDetails":"2 nos"},{"Name":"Fruit bowl","Price":"Rs. 60","IsVeg":"True","ItemDetails":"sweet + roti"}]},{"FoodTypeName":"Lunch","FoodTypeDetails":[{"Name":"Idly","Price":"Rs. 60","IsVeg":"True","ItemDetails":""},{"Name":"Palav","Price":"Rs. 80","IsVeg":"True","ItemDetails":"sweet + rice"}]}]}]},{"FoodCourtName":"Magna","FoodCourtDetails":[{"VendorName":"Polar Bear","VendorDetails":[{"FoodTypeName":"Breakfast","FoodTypeDetails":[{"Name":"Vanilla","Price":"Rs. 40","IsVeg":"True","ItemDetails":"2 nos"},{"Name":"Chocolate","Price":"Rs. 60","IsVeg":"True","ItemDetails":"3 nos"}]}]},{"VendorName":"Wonder Chicken","VendorDetails":[{"FoodTypeName":"Dinner","FoodTypeDetails":[{"Name":"Chicken","Price":"Rs. 100","IsVeg":"False","ItemDetails":"4 nos"}]}]}]}]';
    var resultJSON = eval('(' + json + ')');
    $scope.resultJSON = resultJSON;
}
});

module.directive('foodItem', function () {
var directive = {};
directive.restrict = 'AEC';
directive.template = '{{FoodCourtName}}';
directive.scope = {
    FoodCourtName: "=FoodCourtName"
}
return directive;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="FoodCourtMenuController">
    <input type="search" ng-model="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" placeholder="Search menu" />
    <br />
    <input type="button" ng-click="GetMenu()" value="Get Menu" />

<div id="menu" ng-repeat="x in resultJSON">
        <foodItem FoodCourtName="{{x.FoodCourtName}}"></foodItem> <!--1st scenario-->
        <span food-item food-court-name="{{x.FoodCourtName}}"></span> <!--2nd scenario-->
        <food-item food-court-name="{{x.FoodCourtName}}"></food-item> <!--3rd scenario-->
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm able to populate the data as below using ng-bind, I wanted to use the custom directive, so that i get a better understanding of the same.

Solution would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="menu"  ng-repeat="foodCourt in resultJSON">
            <div ng-repeat="vendor in foodCourt.FoodCourtDetails">
                <div ng-repeat="foodType in vendor.VendorDetails">
                    <div ng-repeat="foodItem in foodType.FoodTypeDetails">
                        <div style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;">
                            <span ng-bind="foodCourt.FoodCourtName" style="padding:10px;"></span>
                            <span ng-bind="vendor.VendorName" style="padding:10px;"></span>
                            <span ng-bind="foodType.FoodTypeName" style="padding:10px;"></span>
                            <span ng-bind="foodItem.Name" style="padding:10px;"></span>
                            <span ng-bind="foodItem.Price" style="padding:10px;"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Well, you have already defined your directive, but you're not using it. You need `<span food-item food-court-name="x.FoodCourtName"></span>` or `<food-item food-court-name="x.FoodCourtName"></food-item>`. Also, use angular.fromJson() or JSON.parse() instead of eval().

Comment: @JBNizet, Updated my HTML as suggested, 
<div id="menu" ng-repeat="x in resultJSON">
            <span food-item food-court-name="x.FoodCourtName"></span>
</div>

But getting an exception on page load, Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…at%20Mc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A13841%2FJS%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A332)

Comment: Start by using angular.js instead of angular.min.js, then restart your app, then post the now readable error message in your question, not in comments.

Comment: Oh, and read Alexander's answer: it's right. I missed the restrict E, so remove it, or use the element-based alternative I suggested.

Comment: @JBNizet, Thank you for ur solution. Now i have updated the query with the updated 1st, 2nd & 3rd scenario in the HTML to call the custom directive and the directive creation in JS. Now, I'm not getting any value (i.e. foodCourtName) populated within the div, but the attribute value "FoodCourtName", "food-court-name" is getting populated with the JSON value. Please let me know how to get the value populated on UI

Comment: The first scenario will not work. The two others will work fine if you change `"=FoodCourtName"` to `"=foodCourtName"`. http://plnkr.co/edit/WFz9xbaVYZHrlFOBxNGa?p=preview. In general, you should respect the JavaScript conventions everywhere: attributes and non-constructor functions start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks mate. The solution worked fine for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132616/discussion-between-manju-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 1):

In directive restrict you set E (element), so you have to use  tag(element), not just an attribute.

Comment: Thank you for ur solution. Now i have updated the query with the updated 1st, 2nd & 3rd scenario in the HTML to call the custom directive and the directive creation in JS.

Now, I'm not getting any value (i.e. foodCourtName) populated within the div, but the attribute value "FoodCourtName", "food-court-name" is getting populated with the JSON value. 

Please let me know how to get the value populated on UI

Comment: Could you create a plucker, so that we have a real-working version, where people can help you?